# syntax error, unexpected unary+, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

getting this unary+ error with the following code, looking at previous solution they suggest that **end** is missing for some condition, But it doesn't look like If that is the case.

Please help

```
<% if part.children.exists? %>
  <% @link_text  += " <b>|</b> " %>
  <% part.children.each do |part_child| %>
    <% if part_child.display_type == "radio" || part_child.display_type == "dropdown" || part_child.display_type == "checkbox" %> 
      <% if part_child.display_type == "checkbox" %>
        <% @checkbox_options = "" %>
        <% part_child.options.each do |o| %> 
          <% if o.is_default? %>
            <% @co = "<span id = 'nav_option_id_" + o.id +"'>" + o.name +"</span>" %>
            <% @checkbox_options += @co %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <% @link_text = @link_text + "<b>#{part_child.name}</b> : <span id='part_child_" + part_child.id.to_s + "'>"  "</span>" %>
      <% else %>
        <% @link_text = @link_text + "<b>#{part_child.name}</b> : <span id='part_child_" + part_child.id.to_s + "'>" + part_child.options.detect{|o| o.is_default?}.try(:name).to_s + "</span>"   + " <b>|</b>  " %>       
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Backtrace? Also, use interpolation rather than string concatenation.

Comment: anything wrong with  string concatenation method above? @BroiSatse

Comment: It is not the best practice - it is extremely hard to read.

Comment: try add o.id.to_s in place of o.id . `"<span id = 'nav_option_id_" + o.id.to_s +"'>"`

Comment: tried that @Dipak .. didn't work

Comment: @Suraj - could you please post a stacktrace?

Comment: Is this the problem `<% @link_text  += " <b>|</b> " %>` `<% @link_text  = " <b>|</b> " %>`

Comment: Besides being harder to read, string concatenation will break if any of the terms aren't a string, whereas interpolation effectively calls "to_s" on everything inside the #{}, to turn it into a string.  eg `"foo #{1}" => "foo 1"`, `"foo" + 1 => TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line is the problem...

```
 <% @link_text = @link_text + "<b>#{part_child.name}</b> : <span id='part_child_" + part_child.id.to_s + "'>"  "</span>" %>
```

It's missing a "+" between the last two elements.

```
 <% @link_text = @link_text + "<b>#{part_child.name}</b> : <span id='part_child_" + part_child.id.to_s + "'>" + "</span>" %>
```

As BrioSatse says in his comment, interpolation would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this please?

```
<% if part.children.exists? %>
    <% @link_text  += " <b>|</b> " %>
    <% part.children.each do |part_child| %>
        <% if %w(radio dropdown checkbox).include?(part_child.display_type) %> 
            <% if part_child.display_type.eql?("checkbox") %>
                <% @checkbox_options = "" %>
                <% part_child.options.each do |o| %> 
                        <% if o.is_default? %>
                        <% @co = "<span id = 'nav_option_id_#{o.id}'>#{o.name}</span>" %>
                        <% @checkbox_options += @co %>
                        <% end %>
                <% end %>
                <% @link_text = @link_text + "<b>#{part_child.name}</b> : <span id='part_child_#{part_child.id.to_s}'></span>" %>
            <% else %>
                <% @link_text = @link_text + "<b>#{part_child.name}</b> : <span id='part_child_#{part_child.id.to_s}'>#{part_child.options.detect{|o| o.is_default?}.try(:name).to_s}</span>"+" <b>|</b> " %>       
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem I thin lies in line:

```
<% @link_text = @link_text + "<b>#{part_child.name}</b> : <span id='part_child_" + part_child.id.to_s + "'>"  "</span>" %>
```

The quotes near the last `</span>` make no sense.
I've also rewritten your ERB output to make it more readable, and a bit shorter. I'm personally a fan of using the #{} notation to merge strings together with variables.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
<% @link_text = @link_text + "<b>#{part_child.name}</b> : <span id='part_child_" + part_child.id.to_s + "'>"  "</span>" %>
```

is missing a `+` before `</span>`.

This highlights the problem of using string concatenation for this - it's an ugly, confusing mess.  This is a much nicer (and unbroken) way to write the above:

```
<% @link_text = += "<b>#{part_child.name}</b> : <span id='part_child_#{part_child.id.to_s}'></span>" %>
```

EDIT:  also, if you're just doing a load of ruby code in your view, and not actually rendering anything, you can wrap the whole lot in a single erb tab, making it much more readable. eg

```
<% 
 if part.children.exists? 
   @link_text  += " <b>|</b> " 
   part.children.each do |part_child| 
     if %w(radio dropdown checkbox).include?(part_child.display_type)  
       if part_child.display_type.eql?("checkbox") 
         @checkbox_options = "" 
         part_child.options.each do |o|  
           if o.is_default? 
           @co = "<span id = 'nav_option_id_#{o.id}'>#{o.name}</span>" 
           @checkbox_options += @co 
           end 
         end 
         @link_text = @link_text + "<b>#{part_child.name}</b> : <span id='part_child_#{part_child.id.to_s}'></span>" 
       else 
         @link_text = @link_text + "<b>#{part_child.name}</b> : <span id='part_child_#{part_child.id.to_s}'>#{part_child.options.detect{|o| o.is_default?}.try(:name).to_s}</span>"+" <b>|</b> "        
       end 
     end 
   end 
 end 
%>
```

Even after doing this, your code still looks like a massively overcomplicated way of achieving something.  It's not railsy to build a massive string of html like this.  You should render the html chunks out seperately, with the logic wrapped around them.